# Why isn't calling wait(), notify() or notifyAll() without a synchronized block not a compiler error?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, synchronization

If we call `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on an object without a `synchronized` block, we get an `IllegalMonitorStateException` at runtime.

Why doesn't the compiler flag me if I try to call these methods without a synchronized block?

Comment: There are 2 kind of exceptions, one that the compiler catch before making the .class file, and one that is caused at runtime and crash everything. IllegalMonitorStateException is a unchecked exception, it means the compiler cant see it, but its caused at runtime.

Comment: Because it's not possible for the compiler to catch all mistakes and it doesn't attempt to.

Comment: on the other side, maybe they can be caught by tools such as pmd and findbugs :-) [not sure, actually]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling those methods only requires that the current thread be the owner of the object`s monitor. However, that could mean calling a method without synchronized from within the context of another synchronized block.

For example:

```
public void doWait(Object o) {
    o.wait(); // you would like the compiler to flag this
}

// but in this case it is valid
synchronized(this)
{
    doWait(this);
}
```

In general, there is now  way to know at compile time whether any piece of code will be executed when the current thread does not hold a particular monitor, which is likely why the compiler does not even try to flag this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to prove that a method further up the stack didn't already obtain the monitor.

For example:

```
class Foo 
{ 
  void foo() 
  { 
    synchronized (bar) 
    { 
      bar.bar(); 
    }
  }
}

class Bar 
{ 
  void bar() 
  { 
    this.wait(); 
  } 
}
```

Would be legal (assuming `bar` is an instance of `Bar`), but impossible to prove that there are is no code that calls `bar` without first obtaining the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

As the execution from one thread to another thread always change at run-time, and you can thing of producer-consumer problem the problem cannot be simulate at compile time, because consumer is consuming the buffer once the buffer is consumed it notifies to producer at that time and till that time producer will wait otherwise there is exception,so the whole logic of these methods is inside synchronized blocks